# Match dataframe column value based on list items and return the list item instead

Tags: python, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe and I want the values of one column to be checked if they match with the values of a list. My initial attempt:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Description': ['foo blah', 'new foo', 'newfoo', 'bar','random']})
keywords_list = ["foo", "bar"]

dataframe = dataframe['Description'].str.split(expand = True).isin(keywords_list).any()

print(dataframe)
```

where I want the dataframe['Description'] to have the values matched from the keywords_list. Something like a replace. None of the following worked:

```
dataframe['Description'] = [x.strip().replace(' ', keywords_list[x]) for x in dataframe['Description']]
```

or

```
dataframe['Description'] = np.where(df['Description'].isin(keywords_list), df['Site'], '')
```

So, the original dataframe:

```
  Description
0    foo blah
1     new foo
2      newfoo
3         bar
4      random
```

should now return:

```
  Description
0    foo
1    foo
2    foo
3    bar
4    random
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build an auxiliary dataframe with one column per keyword, to be able to iterate on the list and prepare the expected result.

This it would be enough to use combine first on those columns to get the expected result:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Description': ['foo blah', 'new foo', 'newfoo', 'bar','random']})
keywords_list = ["foo", "bar"]

# compute a tmp dataframe with a column per keyword and having the keyword
#  as value is there is a match
tmp = pd.DataFrame(index = dataframe.index)
for k in keywords_list:
    tmp.loc[dataframe['Description'].str.contains(k), k] = k

# compute the result by combining all the keyword columns
tmp['resul'] = np.nan
for k in keywords_list:
    tmp['resul'] = tmp['resul'].combine_first(tmp[k])

# update the initial dataframe
dataframe['Description'] = tmp['resul'].combine_first(dataframe['Description'])
```

It gives as expected:

```
  Description
0         foo
1         foo
2         foo
3         bar
4      random
```